# How to stick a footer to the bottom if the page is empty (Tailwind CSS)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm working on a project in Tailwind, and I'd like my footer to have the following behaviour:

- Be sticky to the bottom when there's empty space on the page.
- Get pushed down when the content fills the height of the page (screenshot included)

Here's the [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/) that I'm using to test this. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution for me would be to "flex in column" (`flex flex-col min-h-screen`) parent wrapper and stretch main content (`flex-grow`). It may require to play with parent height sometimes (depends on task)

```html
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
  <div class="flex-grow">
    <!-- Content here -->
  </div>

  <footer class="">
    Footer
  </footer>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/XgTsmVVm5x)